# .NET 3.5 Migration to 4.5 issue with CrystalReports

Tags: vb.net, crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008

I'm migrating an old .NET Framework 3.5 WinForm project to .NET Framework 4.5.2 and then it will be migrated to 4.8 but i have yet some problems with CrystalReports used in that project.

In:

```
   Dim rpt As New CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument
        vedirpt = New CrystalDecisions.Windows.Forms.CrystalReportViewer
        rpt.PrintOptions.PrinterName = DammiPRNPDF()
        rpt.Load("C:\Project\RPT\VEN_ARTORA.rpt")
        rpt.SetDataSource(datsRPT)
```

I get an  exception at like SetDataSource after the  migration with the following stacktrace:

```
CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.DataSourceException
  HResult=0x80041700
  Message=Unknown Query Engine Error
Error in File C:\Users\imytyuk\AppData\Local\Temp\VEN_RC {B1FC7324-0B9F-4E02-A31B-278FD0C30640}.rpt:
Unknown Query Engine Error
  Source=CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.DataSetConversion
  StackTrace:
   at CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.ConvertDotNetToErom.ThrowDotNetException(Exception e)
   at CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument.SetDataSourceInternal(Object val, Type type)
   at CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument.SetDataSource(DataSet dataSet)
   at Project.frmSTATVEL.VediVENRC(Int32 Dal, Int32 Al, String DaDATA, String ADATA, String Excel, String GRUPPO) in E:\VisualStudio\Visual Studio 2019\Project\Project\frmSTATVEL.vb:line 5501
   at Project.frmPRNREP.cmdPRNSCO_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in E:\VisualStudio\Visual Studio 2019\Project\Project\frmPRNREP.vb:line 90
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnClick(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs mevent)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(Message& m, MouseButtons button, Int32 clicks)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ButtonBase.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
   at System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessageW(MSG& msg)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ComponentManager.System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IMsoComponentManager.FPushMessageLoop(IntPtr dwComponentID, Int32 reason, Int32 pvLoopData)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoopInner(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoop(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.RunDialog(Form form)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Form.ShowDialog(IWin32Window owner)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Form.ShowDialog()
   at Project.frmSTATVEL.cmdREPORT_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in E:\VisualStudio\Visual Studio 2019\Project\Project\frmSTATVEL.vb:line 13125
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnClick(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs mevent)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(Message& m, MouseButtons button, Int32 clicks)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ButtonBase.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
   at System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessageW(MSG& msg)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ComponentManager.System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IMsoComponentManager.FPushMessageLoop(IntPtr dwComponentID, Int32 reason, Int32 pvLoopData)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoopInner(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoop(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.RunDialog(Form form)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Form.ShowDialog(IWin32Window owner)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Form.ShowDialog()
   at Project.frmCASSA.cmdRPT_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in E:\VisualStudio\Visual Studio 2019\Project\Project\frmCASSA.vb:line 41283
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnClick(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs mevent)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(Message& m, MouseButtons button, Int32 clicks)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ButtonBase.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
   at System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessageW(MSG& msg)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ComponentManager.System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IMsoComponentManager.FPushMessageLoop(IntPtr dwComponentID, Int32 reason, Int32 pvLoopData)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoopInner(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoop(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
   at Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices.WindowsFormsApplicationBase.OnRun()
   at Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices.WindowsFormsApplicationBase.DoApplicationModel()
   at Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices.WindowsFormsApplicationBase.Run(String[] commandLine)
   at Project.My.MyApplication.Main(String[] Args) in :line 83

  This exception was originally thrown at this call stack:
    [External Code]

Inner Exception 1:
COMException: Unknown Query Engine Error
Error in File C:\Users\imytyuk\AppData\Local\Temp\VEN_RC {B1FC7324-0B9F-4E02-A31B-278FD0C30640}.rpt:
Unknown Query Engine Error
```

What can be done without changing the CR version? the projects uses CRRedis 2008

Comment: Well, reading the support documents it looks to me the latest compatible framework for CR2008 is .Net 4.5.1,.  It's been out of support since Dec 2015 so maybe you only real option is to either upgrade to the latest or look at other reporting toolsets if you're looking to modernise.  I would question exactly what the goal of migrating to 4.8 is though?

Comment: @Hursey i need to use the latest features from .NET Framework like WebView2 and as i was yet migrating it to 4.5.2 (minimum required for WebView2) i was going to upgrade it to the latest one. 
I've solved the issue i'd post an answer in minutes..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make the older version of CrystalReport works on .NET Framework 4.5.2 and above i had to add the `useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy` set to `true` in `app.config` file.

So the line from this:

```
<startup><supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5.2" /></startup>
```

Become this:

```
<startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true"><supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5.2" /></startup>
```